# .jpg.to alternative to get URL from Image Keyword

Tags: java, android, image, search

I'm trying to get a simple way to extract a relevant image url given a "keyword". In browser, *.jpg.to  does it perfectly.

For example, if I type book.jpg.to, it'll return a picture of a book. However, Java doesn't seem to accept ".to" as a domain and (in android) gives me an error complaining about the host name.

Are there any alternatives or solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a similar service [LoremFlickr](http://loremflickr.com/) which returns random picture for given keyword. And you can also specify dimensions of the image.

Usage:

```
<img src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240/book" />
```